# Difference between exit() and return in main() function in C

Tags: c

I've looked through the links [What is the difference between exit and return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463551/difference-between-exit-and-return)
and
[return statement vs exit() in main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461449/return-statement-vs-exit-in-main)
to find the answer, but in vain.

Problem with the first link is that the answer assumes `return` from any function. I want to know the exact difference between the two when in main() function. Even if there's a little difference I'd like to know what it is. Which is preferred and why? Is there any performance gain in using `return` over exit() (or exit() over `return`) with all sorts of compiler optimizations turned off?

Problem with the second link is I'm not interested in knowing what happens in C++. I want the answer specifically pertaining to C.

EDIT:
After recommendation by a person, I actually tried to compare the assembly output of the following programs:

Note: Using `gcc -S <myprogram>.c`

Program mainf.c:

```
int main(void){
 return 0;
}
```

Assembly output:

```
    .file   "mainf.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Program mainf1.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
 exit(0);
}
```

Assembly output:

```
    .file   "mainf1.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $0, %edi
    call    exit
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Noting that I'm not well versed with assembly, I can see some differences between the 2 programs with the `exit()` version being shorter than `return` version. What's the difference?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23836332/2505965) from the first question seems appropriate, no?

Comment: Did you read the other answers to the second question? Several of them talk about C specifically.

Comment: Are you looking for C-Standard-compliant answers or are you interested in the instruction level of things (kernel code, binaries structure, etc)?

Comment: Instruction level of things.

Answer (score 6):

There is practically no difference between calling `exit` or executing `return` from `main` as long as `main` returns a type that is compatible with `int`.

From the C11 Standard:

> **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**
>
> 1 If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument;  reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

Comment: There are actually small differences in the generated assembly.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, I should've emphasised **equivalent**.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer: This answer does not quote the C Standards.**

## TL;DR

Both the methods *jump* into **GLibC code**, and to know exactly what that code is doing or which one is faster or more efficient, you'll need to read them. If you want to know more about the GLibC, you should check the sources for the GCC and GLibC. There are links in the end for those.

---

### Syscalls, wrappers and GLibC

**First:** there's a difference between [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) and [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html). The first is a [GLibC](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) wrapper around the second, which is a [system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). The one we use in our program, and requires the inclusion of `stdlib.h` is `exit(3)` - the GLibC wrapper, **not** the system call.

Now, programs **are not** just **your** simple instructions. They contain heavy loads of GLibC's *own instructions*. These GLibC functions serve several purposes related to loading and providing the library functionality you use. For that to work GLibC must be "inside" your program.

So, how is GLibC inside your program? Well, it puts itself there through your compiler (it sets some static code and some hooks into the dynamic library) - most likely you're using [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

---

### The 'return 0;' method

I suppose you know what [stack frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057443/explain-the-concept-of-a-stack-frame-in-a-nutshell) are, so I won't explain what they are. The cool thing to notice is that `main()` itself has it's own stack frame. And that stack frame returns somewhere **and it must** return... But, to **where**?

Lets compile the following:

```
int main(void)
{
        return 0;
}
```

And compile and debug it with:

```
$ gcc -o main main.c

$ gdb main

(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x00000000004005e8 <+0>:     push   %rbp
0x00000000004005e9 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000004005ec <+4>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004005f1 <+9>:     pop    %rbp
0x00000000004005f2 <+10>:    retq
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) break main
(gdb) run 
Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004005ec in main ()  
(gdb) stepi
...
```

Now, `stepi` will make for the fun part. This will jump **one instruction** at a time, so it's perfect to follow function calls. After you press run `stepi` for the first time, just hold your finger on ENTER until you get tired.

What you must observe is the sequence in which functions are called with this method. You see, `ret` is a "jumping" instruction (**edit:** after [David Hoelzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191105/david-hoelzer) comment, I see that calling `ret` a simple jump is an over-generalization): after we pop `rbp`, `ret` itself will pop the return pointer from the stack and jump to it. So, if GLibC built that stack frame, `retq` is making our `return 0;` C statement jump right into GLibC's own code! How clever!

The order of function calls I got started roughly like this:

```
__libc_start_main
exit
__run_exit_handlers
_dl_fini
rtld_lock_default_lock_recursive
_dl_fini
_dl_sort_fini
```

---

### The 'exit(0);' method

Compiling this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
        exit(0);
}
```

And compiling and debugging...

```
$ gcc -o exit exit.c

$ gdb exit
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000400628 <+0>:     push   %rbp
0x0000000000400629 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x000000000040062c <+4>:     mov    $0x0,%edi
0x0000000000400631 <+9>:     callq  0x4004d0 <exit@plt>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) break main
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040062c in main ()
(gdb) stepi
...
```

And the function sequence I got was:

```
exit@plt
??
_dl_runtime_resolve
_dl_fixup
_dl_lookup_symbol_x
do_lookup_x
check_match
_dl_name_match
strcmp
```

---

### List object's Symbols

There's a cool tool for printing the symbols defined within a binary. It's [nm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html). I suggest you take a look into it as it will give you an idea of how much "crap" it's added in a simple program like the ones above.

To use it in the simplest form:

```
$ nm main
$ nm exit
```

That will print a list of symbols in the file. Note that this list **does not** include references these functions will make. So if a given function in this list calls another function, the other probably won't be in the list.

---

### Conclusion

It depends heavily on the way the GLibC choses to handle a simple stack frame return from `main` and how it implements the `exit` wrapper. In the end, the `_exit(2)` system call will get called and you'll exit your process.

**Finally**, to really answer your question: both the methods jump into GLibC code, and to know exactly what that code is doing you'll need to read it. If you want to know more about the GLibC, you should check the sources for the GCC and GLibC.

---

### References

- [GLibC Source Repository](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html): Look in `stdlib/exit.c` and `stdlib/exit.h` for the implementations.
- [Linux Kernel Exit Definition](https://github.com/torvalds/linux): look in `kernel/exit.c` for the `_exit(2)` system call implementation, and `include/syscalls.h` for the preprocessor magic behind it.
- [GCC Sources](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/): I do not know the `gcc` (compiler, not suite) sources, and would appreciate if anyone could point out where the runtime sequence is defined.

Comment: Though wordy this answers captures the essential implementation difference. Note that "look at the C runtime to see what return does" is true for other tool sets besides gcc.

Comment: There's more than a subtle difference to me between a `call` into glibc and a `ret` that uses the return pointer on the stack to return to glibc.  I would really hesitate to call `ret` a *jump* into libc.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I didn't say that `ret` is a jump into _libc_. I said it's jumping into libc in these cases. After the `rbp` pop, `ret` will pop the return address and jump to it. However, I'm curious on how you'd define those `ret`s. Could you explain?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I think I see what you mean. I edited the answer, would you take a look and see if it's clearer now?

Comment: Well, I just wouldn't word it this way:  "Both the methods jump into GLibC code, and to know exactly what that code is doing or which one is faster or more efficient, you'll need to read them"

Answer (score 4):

Functionally, from the `main()` function there is really no difference in C.  For example, even if you defined a function handler with the `atexit()` library call, both `return()` and `exit()` from main will call that function pointer.

The `exit()` call, however, has the flexibility that you can use it to cause a program to exit with a return code from any point within the code.

There are the technical differences.  If you compile the following to assembly:

```
int main()
{
  return 1;
}
```

the final portion of that code will be:

```
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, -4(%rbp)
popq %rbp
retq
```

On the other hand, the following code compiled to assembly:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  exit(1);
}
```

will be identical in all respects except that it ends as follows:

```
subq $16, %rsp
movl $1, %edi
movl $0, -4(%rbp)
callq _exit
```

Aside from the 1 being put into `EDI` rather than `EAX` as is required on the platform where I compiled this code as the calling convention to the `_exit` call, you'll note two differences.  First, a stack alignment operation takes place to prepare for the function call.  Second, rather than terminating with a `retq`, we are now calling into the system library, which will handle the final return code and return.

Answer (score 3):

`exit` is a system call while `return` is an instruction of the language.

`exit` terminates current process, `return` returns from a function call.

In the `main()` function, they both accomplish the same thing:

```
int main() {
    // code
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // code
    exit(0);
}
```

While in a function:

```
void f() {
    // code
    return; // return to where it was called from.
}

void f() {
    // code
    exit(0); // terminates program
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One major difference between using `return` and calling `exit()` in the `main()` program is that if you call `exit()`, the local variables in the `main()` still exist and are valid, whereas if you `return`, they are not.

This matters if you've done anything such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void function_using_stdout(void)
{
    char space[512];
    char *base = space;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        base += sprintf(base, "Hysterical raisins #%d (continued) ", j+1);
        printf("%d..%d: %.24s\n", j*24, j*24+23, space + j * 24);
    }
    printf("Catastrophic elegance\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[64];  // Deliberately rather small
    setvbuf(stdout, buffer, _IOFBF, sizeof(buffer));
    atexit(function_using_stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        function_using_stdout();
    printf("All done - exiting now\n");
    if (argc > 1)
        return 1;
    else
        exit(2);
}
```

because now the function called (via `atexit()`) from the startup code that called `main()` doesn't have a valid buffer for standard output.  Whether it crashes or merely gets thoroughly confused or prints garbage or appears to work is open to debate.

I called the program `hysteresis`.  When run with no arguments, it used `exit()` and worked correctly/sanely (the local `space` variable in `function_using_stdout()` was not sharing space with the I/O buffer for `stdout`):

```
$ ./hysteresis 
'hysteresis' is up to date.
0..23: Hysterical raisins #1 (c
24..47: ontinued) Hysterical rai
48..71: sins #2 (continued) Hyst
72..95: erical raisins #3 (conti
96..119: nued) Hysterical raisins
120..143:  #4 (continued) Hysteric
144..167: al raisins #5 (continued
168..191: ) Hysterical raisins #6 
192..215: (continued) Hysterical r
216..239: aisins #7 (continued) Hy
Catastrophic elegance
0..23: Hysterical raisins #1 (c
24..47: ontinued) Hysterical rai
48..71: sins #2 (continued) Hyst
72..95: erical raisins #3 (conti
96..119: nued) Hysterical raisins
120..143:  #4 (continued) Hysteric
144..167: al raisins #5 (continued
168..191: ) Hysterical raisins #6 
192..215: (continued) Hysterical r
216..239: aisins #7 (continued) Hy
Catastrophic elegance
0..23: Hysterical raisins #1 (c
24..47: ontinued) Hysterical rai
48..71: sins #2 (continued) Hyst
72..95: erical raisins #3 (conti
96..119: nued) Hysterical raisins
120..143:  #4 (continued) Hysteric
144..167: al raisins #5 (continued
168..191: ) Hysterical raisins #6 
192..215: (continued) Hysterical r
216..239: aisins #7 (continued) Hy
Catastrophic elegance
All done - exiting now
0..23: Hysterical raisins #1 (c
24..47: ontinued) Hysterical rai
48..71: sins #2 (continued) Hyst
72..95: erical raisins #3 (conti
96..119: nued) Hysterical raisins
120..143:  #4 (continued) Hysteric
144..167: al raisins #5 (continued
168..191: ) Hysterical raisins #6 
192..215: (continued) Hysterical r
216..239: aisins #7 (continued) Hy
Catastrophic elegance
$
```

When called with at least one argument, things went haywire (the local `space` variable in `function_using_stdout()` was probably sharing space with the I/O buffer for `stdout` — unless that was being used by the code that executes the functions registered with `atexit()`):

```
$ ./hysteresis aleph
0..23: Hysterical raisins #1 (c
24..47: ontinued) Hysterical rai
48..71: sins #2 (continued) Hyst
72..95: erical raisins #3 (conti
96..119: nued) Hysterical raisins
120..143:  #4 (continued) Hysteric
144..167: al raisins #5 (continued
168..191: ) Hysterical raisins #6 
192..215: (continued) Hysterical r
216..239: aisins #7 (continued) Hy
Catastrophic elegance
0..23: Hysterical raisins #1 (c
24..47: ontinued) Hysterical rai
48..71: sins #2 (continued) Hyst
72..95: erical raisins #3 (conti
96..119: nued) Hysterical raisins
120..143:  #4 (continued) Hysteric
144..167: al raisins #5 (continued
168..191: ) Hysterical raisins #6 
192..215: (continued) Hysterical r
216..239: aisins #7 (continued) Hy
Catastrophic elegance
0..23: Hysterical raisins #1 (c
24..47: ontinued) Hysterical rai
48..71: sins #2 (continued) Hyst
72..95: erical raisins #3 (conti
96..119: nued) Hysterical raisins
120..143:  #4 (continued) Hysteric
144..167: al raisins #5 (continued
168..191: ) Hysterical raisins #6 
192..215: (continued) Hysterical r
216..239: aisins #7 (continued) Hy
Catastrophic elegance
Al) Hysterical raisins #2 (continued) l raisins #1 (c
24..47: ontinued) Hysterical rai
48..71: l rai
48..71: nued) Hyst
72..95: 71: nued) Hyst
72..95: 7
96..119: nued) Hysterical raisins
120..143:  #4 (continued) Hysteric
144..167: al raisins #5 (continued
168..191: ) Hysterical raisins #6 
192..215: (continued) Hysterical r
216..239: aisins #7 (continued) Hy
Catastrophic elegance
$
```

Most of the time, this sort of thing isn't a problem.  However, when it matters, it really does matter.  And, note, it isn't visible as a problem until the program is exiting — which can make it tricky to debug.