# What is the difference between return 1 and exit (1) from a C main function?

Tags: c, return, exit

In a C program, within the main function, is there a difference between

```
exit(1);
```

and

```
return 1;
```

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between exit and return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463551/what-is-the-difference-between-exit-and-return)

Comment: From the `main()` function, no. But from any other function, yes.

Answer (score -1):

`exit` represents immediate termination which will terminate program.

In the below program when we `return value` from main the destructors will be called but not in case when we use `exit(value).`

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class String {
private:
    char* s;
    int size;
 
public:
    String(char*); // constructor
    ~String(); // destructor
};
 
String::String(char* c){
    cout<<"Calling constructor"<<endl;
    size = strlen(c);
    s = new char[size + 1];
    strcpy(s, c);
}
String::~String() {
    cout<<"Calling destructor"<<endl;
        delete[] s; 
}

int main(){
    String s("Hell o");

    exit(1);
    //return 1;
}
```

Comment: While highly educational for C++ programmers, the OP was asking about, and likewise tagged for, C, not C++.