# Syntax Error when using 'delete'

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

I have a problem when using 'delete' operator. It is identified as a syntax error by VS2013 with Nov 2013 CTP compiler, giving the message: "expected a declaration". Here is the code:

```
int a = 1;
int* p = &a;

int* snj = new int[10];

delete p;
delete[] snj;
```

Comment: Is this the complete code?

Comment: You have to put the code inside a function.

Comment: Yes, it is complete.

Comment: the `delete` shouldn't be a syntax error (assuming this code is in a function body), but it is a logical error to delete a pointer that wasn't obtained with `new`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Putting the code inside the function worked. May I ask why? P.S. Sorry, I'm just a beginner. :)

Comment: OH I got it, so stupid omg

Comment: I didn't even put it in main, so code was actually not able to run anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't let you write arbitrary expressions in the top-level like Python or other languages. You need to place your code in a function, probably `main` in this case:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int* p = &a;

    int* snj = new int[10];

    delete p;
    delete[] snj;
}
```

Note that using `delete` on a pointer which wasn't allocated using `new` is undefined behaviour.

Things like this are very basic and should be covered by your introductory book. If you don't have an introductory book, you should [get one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Whilst your answer is semantically correct, it's not valid code without a `return` statement

Comment: @EdChum What do you mean? `main` has an implicit `return 0;`.

Comment: Really, I thought you had to explicitly `return 0;` or whatever, news to me

Comment: [Nope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239/why-does-int-main-compile).

Comment: OK found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189885/why-is-explicitly-returning-0-from-main-considered-good-practice) I take it back

Answer (score 0):

p points to the address of a. a is a local variable decalred on the stack. You can only call delete on dynalically allocated heap memory (Any variable created using the new keyword).

a is deleted automatically when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should not delete p since it is not pointing to a heap element, it points to a stack element.