# Which is a better choice to exit a Console, "FreeConsole (void)", "return 0", or "exit (EXIT_SUCCESS)"?

Tags: c++, c, function, winapi, mingw32

I know about the difference between between [`return` vs `exit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461449/return-statement-vs-exit-in-main).
I want to know how they are different from `FreeConsole()`.

1. [`FreeConsole()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150(v=vs.85).aspx) is an API Function
2. `(scope: main function) return` is a statement in C.
3. `exit (EXIT_SUCCESS)` is a function call.

Which would you like to use in C to exit a program and why?

Comment: `return` only exits the program if called from `main`, so it's not the same as `exit`.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore Sorry. I have revised this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [return statement vs exit() in main()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461449/return-statement-vs-exit-in-main)

Comment: Calling `exit` does not call the destructors of local variables; returning from `main` does.  And according to the documentation, `FreeConsole` doesn't terminate the process at all; it just disconnects it from the controlling console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which would you like to use in C to exit a program? Why and why not?

I wouldn't use `FreeConsole()` because I never program for Microsoft platforms; you shouldn't use it if you want your code to be portable. From the documentation you link to, it seems to do something completely different (detach from the console without ending the program), so you can't use it to end the program in any case.

Within `main`, I'd use `return` to ensure local variables are destroyed. `exit()` won't do that. (Although that's a habit from C++; in C, it makes little difference).

To end the program from other functions, `return` won't work, so I'd use `exit()`. But only if I'm convinced that it makes sense to end the program at that point.

> In my opinion, return and exit() are the same. Is it correct?

From `main()`, almost. `return` will destroy local variables before ending the program; `exit()` won't.

(That only applies to C++; in C, where nothing has a destructor, they are effictively the same. Perhaps you should restrict your questions to one language at a time; I didn't initially notice that you'd tagged the question with two different languages.)

From other functions, they obviously aren't the same at all.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. It really helps. :-)

Answer (score 6):

In C, calling `exit` is equivalent to returning from `main`.

In C++, calling `exit` will bypass stack unwinding, so destructors will not be invoked properly (IOW, you almost always want to avoid it).

`FreeConsole` frees a console without exiting the program. The process can continue to execute detached after freeing the console. As such, it's not really even close to equivalent to either of the other two. Of course, `FreeConsole` is a Win32 API function, so using it also renders the code non-portable.

Comment: `FreeConsole` is also non-portable, obviously.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Yeah, that seemed obvious, but as you hint, it's probably worth mentioning explicitly.