# return vs exit in FreeBSD /bin/ and /usr/bin

Tags: c, return, exit, freebsd

I noticed that the FreeBSD code in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` have some fix to use `exit` instead of `return`, what does that mean?

All I have in my thought is that the `return` statement may cause `vfork(2)` to corrupt the stack frame, is that the only reason for this? If that was true, then why just a portion of the commands in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` got fixes, not all of them?

Comment: Can you point to something more concrete? Like a commit, a list of source files, or something? This question is very hard to understand without more context.

Comment: freeBSD `/bin/df` has a commit 'Use exit() instead of return in `main()`' recently, but /bin/cat still use `return` in `main()`.

Comment: @oxnz: maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5856935/214671

Comment: Sorry, but no. This is the commit which confused me. https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/5ec82107b61b159ab874773644b3df4880e4874e

Comment: found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461449/return-statement-vs-exit-in-main

Comment: It's simply good style and robust practice to use `exit()` wherever the intention is to terminate the program, even within `main()`.  The commit author's reasoning and justification was confused and vastly over-thought, and full of unsubstantiated assumptions.  There is a difference between `return` and `exit()` from `main()`, but it is totally irrelevant in this specific example.

Answer (score 1):

According to [5.1.2.2.3p1](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3p1)

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument

This rules out your *corrupt the stack frame* theory; `return 0;` is functionally identical to `exit(0);` for conforming C implementations (at least for non-recursive `main` entry points).

I would suggest that this change was merely stylistic, or perhaps guided by ignorance. Another possibility is that the author has the desire to transform `main` into a recursive function (or `main` has already been turned into a recursive function; idk, I just did a quick grep and it doesn't seem immediately recursive). Finally, as the last grim alternative, perhaps the C implementation that FreeBSD uses is non-conforming (I sure hope not!)...

**edit**: It just occurred to me by reading through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5856935/1989425) that this could have been a work-around for a compiler bug, but alas I checked the source code for usage of `atexit` and could find no reason to pursue this line of reasoning any further.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can amalgamate the various links provided by others into an appropriate answer.

---

[**As far as the C language is concerned, there is no difference.**](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3p1)

A call to `exit()` does

1. call the functions registered with `atexit()`;
2. flushes and closes the output streams;
3. removes files opened with `tmpfile()`;
4. returns control to the environment.

A `return <n>` from main is equivalent to `exit( <n> )`.

---

[**Some flawed static code analyzers think different.**](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/svn-src-head/2015-August/075812.html)

As far as the C language is concerned, **memory allocated by `main()` and not `free()`d is *leaked*.** Unix cleans up at process termination, but not all operating systems do (!).

Apparently, some static code analyzers consider memory still allocated at the point of `exit()` to be *not leaked* (while they do for `return` from `main()`), **which is why that commit was made** (to get rid of the warning).

*This is a workaround for a* bug *in the code analyzer.*

---

[**As far as the C++ language is concerned, there is *a lot* of difference.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/461528/60281)

When you `return` from `main()`, you are leaving the scope of the function, which means local objects get destroyed.

Since C++ programmers enjoy the benefits of deterministic destruction (as opposed to e.g. Java which might or might not execute your destructor even on VM termination...), they tend to make their destructors do more than just freeing memory. Network connections, temporary files, terminal windows locked by `ncurses`, all that kind of goodness, which C programmers would have to care for manually or use `atexit()` for.

When you call [`std::exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) from `main()`, that function *directly turns over control to the runtime*. The `main()` function never returns, the process gets terminated *without* calling the destructors of `main()`-local objects.

Moreover, while `std::exit()` is defined to flush and close the **C** output streams, *there is no such provision for the **C++** output streams*.

Comment: You're over-thinking things too much and making assumptions.   (1) There *is* a difference between `return` and `exit()` from `main()`, and that is to do with the lifetime of objects defined in `main()` which have automatic-storage duration (and the rare possibility they might be referenced by a callback registered with `atexit()`).  (2)  Any memory allocated anywhere and not freed before `exit()` is leaked.  There is nothing special about `main()`.  There is no actual static analyzer that will be confused (the author was also making assumptions and was confused).  (3) C++ is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a very good reason for doing that, in my opinion.

This particular change is discussed in [this post](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/svn-src-head/2015-August/075812.html) on the freebsd mailing list.

The short story is that the commit log should be

"Use exit() instead of return in main() to work around a broken static analyzer"

So it's to help static analyzers, and memory analyzers that would otherwise report stuff allocated in main() as a memory leak - which most simple utilities doesn't bother to de-allocate since the process is anyway going to exit.