# Time Limit Exceeded c++ algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm currently doing an algorithm that given a sequence, checks if there is a subsequence which sum equals a given value. If I have:

```
3 8
10
5
1
7 5
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
0 0
```

where 3 8 and 7 5 are the (sequence size, value) and 0 0 tells us we reached the end. In this case it would print :

```
SUBSEQUENCE NOT FOUND
SUBSEQUENCE FOUND AT POSITION 2
```

My question is, why am I getting a Time Limit Exceeded when I submit it to Mooshak? Here goes the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int tamanho;
    int valor;
    int soma, numero;
    int sequencia[100];



    while(1){ 

        scanf("%d %d", &tamanho, &valor);

        if(tamanho != 0 && valor != 0){

            for(int i = 1; i <= tamanho; i++){
                scanf("%d", &numero);
                printf("%d\n", i);
                sequencia[i] = numero;
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }

            for(int i = 1; i < tamanho; i++){
                printf("i");
                for(int j = i; j < tamanho; j++){
                    soma = 0;
                    printf("j");
                    for (int z = i; z < j; z++){
                        printf("z");
                        soma = soma + sequencia[z];
                    }
                    if(soma == valor){
                        printf("SUBSEQUENCIA NA POSICAO %d \n", i);
                        exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("SUBSEQUENCIA NAO ENCONTRADA\n");    
        }   
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please, post the link to the problem, or paste here the input limits.

Comment: Are the values in the sequences guaranteed to be positive (or at least non-negative)?

Comment: You only exit the `while (1)` loop when the subsequence was found (in fact, you exit the program); if no subsequence is ever found, your program busy waits forever, which will eventually cause a timeout.

Comment: Input goes from 0 to 1000, Core size 0 Kb
Data of execute 32 Mb
Execution output 500 Kb
Stack of execute 1 Mb
Program code 100 Kb
Real time timeout 60 sec
Compilation timeout 60 sec
Execution timeout * 5 sec

Comment: @MaxLybbert - I think you found the problem. You should post a fix as the answer.

Comment: Mooshak is a system for managing programming contests on the Web

Comment: @PedroCaseiro  `for(int i = 1; i <= tamanho; i++)`  Arrays start from 0, not 1.  If you input 100 values in `tamanho`, you have a memory overwrite.

Comment: @PedroCaseiro WTH is a _Time limit exceeded_?? New kind of exception I didn't heard of yet? (I hate OJ questions)

Comment: @πάντα - It seems like it's an error message from the Mooshak contest system.

Comment: Already solved the time limit exceeded. It was what @maxLybbert said :) Thanks.

Comment: BTW, with cumulative sum, solution can be reduced to `O(n²)` instead of `O(n^3)`

Comment: @jarod42 this is the first exercise and we're supposed to use this algorithm. Exercise number 2 uses cumulative sum. Thanks for the tip anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. Inside your top-level `while` loop, replace this:

```
if(tamanho != 0 && valor != 0){
    // logic for one sequence
}
```

with:

```
if(tamanho == 0 && valor == 0){
    return 0;
}

// logic for one sequence
```

(This is based on the comment by @MaxLybbert).

P.S. As a general rule (there are some rare exceptions), you should use `return 0;` from `main()` instead of calling `exit(0);`. See the accepted answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461449/535871) for why. For your particular code, however, it doesn't make any difference.