# Qtwebengineprocess is not closed after application closing

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I have an application that uses Qt WebEngine. But I found that after closing my application or after crashing it "Qtwebengineprocess" still stays on. My app is too big to show it here, but here is a little example which also demostrates the problem:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QTimer>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWebEngineView* viewer = new QWebEngineView(NULL);
    viewer->show();
    viewer->load(QUrl("https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Pets/spark/royal-canin/tabby-kitten-small.jpg?imwidth=1400"));
    QTimer::singleShot(2000, []() {
        exit(-1);
    });
    app.exec();
    delete viewer;

    return 0;
}
```

Did I forget to set up some thing? Or this is a Qt bug? Thanks in advance.

**UPD**: Qt 5.11, Win10

Comment: Why do you say that the "Qtwebengineprocess" still remains?

Comment: @eyllanesc, because it still remains. I can find it in the task manager

Comment: I just tried it in linux and the process disappears when the window closes. Does the process remain forever or does it die after a while?

Comment: @eyllanesc, process remain forever consuming CPU. I forgot to say, that I'm doing this on Windows

Comment: I recommend you to indicate the version of Qt, what is the version of your OS, etc, but it smells like a bug, report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found actual issue and solution - [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69030) . This is Qt 5.11 bug that describes exactly this problem.

And one of the comments had solution that worked for me:

```
When running with QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES); 
at the top of the main() function, I'm observing that the qtwebengine process closes correctly, 
both when stopping the debugger and when the release exe crashes.
```

Just added that line before creation of my `qApp` and saw no crash whatsoever. Of course this comes with benefits and disadvantages of using ANGLE vs dynamic GPU on Qt, [more details here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html).

Comment: It is strange, but I tried this solution for second time and it work now :/ Indeed, there are no WebEngine processes left anymore. This solution is fine for me, thank you!

Comment: note, that it should be fixed in Qt 5.12 as noted in bug url i linked in answer

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in PyQt 5.11 and above. After reinstalling my OS and installing the latest version of PyQt (5.11.3) I experienced this and other issues with QWebEngineView not resizing properly in layouts. Downgraded to PyQt 5.10.1 and everything ran properly again. If using Python, just run:

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip install PyQt5==5.10.1
```

Comment: Thank's, but I use C++, not python. But I will test this bug on another versions of Qt

Comment: Yeah, my bad, didn't read the tags. But the same concept applies, downgrade to 5.10.1 and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461449/return-statement-vs-exit-in-main) , when `exit()` is called in `main()`, no destructor will be called for locally scoped objects! `exit()` does not return.

Any code placed after `app.exec()`, (in your case `delete viewer;`), would be executed ONLY after main eventloop quits/exits and returns to caller, Your timer is calling (stdlib) `exit()` from within main loop, which means: you are exiting execution without return to caller, AND, none of your code placed AFTER `app.exec()` would be executed, if you want your code to run correctly and execute `delete viewer;`, then timer should quit main event loop thus you need to call `app.quit()` or `app.exit(-1)`.

Comment: Yes, I know It. But the problem is that even without exit(-1) it sometimes have same behaviour as in the question. And also in linux this process is closed in any way.

Comment: @user2123079, this is almost waste of time. I run the corrected snippet on (win10/64 and Qt5.11/msvc2017 kit) and no bug is observed.

Comment: strange.. have the same environment.. I will make more experiments

Comment: process named "Qtwebengineprocess" which consumes CPU

Comment: @user2123079 How do run the application?

Comment: Double click on it or from Visual Studio - there is no difference

Comment: @user2123079, are you aware that `QWebEngine` should run only in `release` mode?

Comment: Problem remains for both debug and release builds

Comment: I observe same problem in qt 5.11 / vs 17 only if you terminate app sooner then page correctly loads. Try to load instead of jpg some heavy page that takes time to load and quit app. Webengine process will not be terminated. This is even worse if you have several QWQebengineviews running at the same time in app and user terminate app prematurely.

Comment: In qt 5.7 such issue was not present

Comment: @Shf, I will experiment with Qt versions and this bug. As soon as it will be done, I'll reply here about results