# Difference between system("PAUSE) return EXIT_SUCCESS and return 0

Tags: c++

Is there any difference if I use `return 0`  instead of:

```
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS
```

Here is the script:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World!";

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/461855/10957435)

Comment: `system("PAUSE")` is irrelevant here.

Comment: if i only use "return 0" as the end of the script, there will be the same result even system("PAUSE") is omitted

Comment: I prefer using `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` or `return EXIT_FAILURE;` because it conveys the intended meaning.  In practice, my position is in the minority, and you also have to remember to `#include <cstdlib>`.  Also, in C++, you can omit the return in the `main` routine, and that will do an implied `return 0;`, which is fairly common practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXIT_SUCCESS` is a constant for the successfull execution of the program. See [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/stdlib.h.html)

```
#define EXIT_SUCCESS    0   /* Successful exit status.  */
```

The command `system("PAUSE")` generate a command line pause (only for Windows!). So this command is indepentend of your `return 0` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: so..  is system("pause")  really necessary during coding?I think it can be omitted

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) discussion for an answer. `system("pause")` is windows only (so there is no linux or other OS equivalent) and a bad practice.

Comment: `return 0;` and `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` are both required to return an appropriate value that indicates success. That's usually 0, but it doesn't have to be; it depends on the system's convention. The other portable return value is `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: But this shouldn´t be a problem when you use the `stdlib.h` or is this wrong? Sure you can´t use this macro when no `stdlib.h` is available for your target system, so you have to check if the correct return value is `0` or something else.